# laravel eloquent: many to many relations

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I would like to add some items in my db table pivot using eloquent ->attach but i don' t understand why it don't work:

I have 2 models (Salade=>(table 'salades' in DB) and Ingredient=>(table 'ingredients' in DB), 
the pivot table is ingredient_salade( 3columns : id, ingredient_id,salade_id).

My Models:

```
class Ingredient extends Model
{
protected $table = 'ingredients';

protected $fillable = ['nom'];

public function Salades()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Salade');
} 
}


class Salade extends Model
{
protected $table = 'salades';

protected $fillable = ['nom','prix'];

public function ingredients()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Ingredient');
}
}
```

SaladeController@Store

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
                        'nom' => 'required',
                            'prix' => 'required' ]);


$salade = $request->only(['nom', 'prix']);

// insert new salade in DB
$lanouvelleSalade = \App\Salade::create($salade);

//insert relation in pivot table
$lanouvelleSalade->ingredients()->attach([21,22,23]);

    return redirect('salade')->withOk("Le Salade " . $request->input('name') . " a été modifié.");

}
```

the tables:
[image of the tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdckj.jpg)
the new salade is insert in table salades but the relation in Pivot is not insert. Why?

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
$lanouvelleSalade->ingredients()->attach([21,22,23]);
```

to:

```
$lanouvelleSalade->ingredients()->sync([21,22,23]);
```

Comment: @FredMoras You should check Mohammad b's answer to make sure you have defined the relationship correctly, and then change attach() to sync().

Answer (score 0):

replace your relation codes with this codes and check it:

**Ingredient** Class:

```
public function Salades()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Salade','ingredient_salade','ingredient_id','salade_id');
}
```

And **Salade** Class:

```
public function ingredients()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Ingredient','ingredient_salade','salade_id','ingredient_id');
}
```

let me know if you have any error

Comment: hi mohammad, i have this error . SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`tuto`.`ingredient_salade`, CONSTRAINT `salade_ingredient_ingredient_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`ingredient_id`) REFERENCES `ingredients` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `ingredient_salade` (`ingredient_id`, `salade_id`) values (60, 21))     the ingredient (60) doesn't exist. it seems that the column are exchanged

Comment: @FredMoras are you sure there are these id's  21,22,23 in ingredients table?

Comment: yes 100% but look my error : SQL: insert into ingredient_salade (ingredient_id, salade_id) values (60, 21)) in this case the '21' is the second value, but ingredient_id is the first column...

Comment: @FredMoras I update and correct my answer check it again

Comment: @FredMoras as you image that you sent everything is ok , what do you expect?

Comment: @FredMoras  But there is no error in image that you sent